# Band used for deformation estimation using In-SAR

Tags: remote-sensing, terrain, sentinel-snap, sar, insar

Which polarization of SAR data (C-band - Sentinel-1A) shall I use to get a better deformation map of a mountain terrain - VV or HH?

Comment: Can you provide some additional details, such as what wavelength you're planning on using?

Comment: @ycartwhelen I want to use Sentinel 1A data, so which polarization band shall I use for better results?